# SQL edit column1 if column2 = a

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db in the following table:

type__ number

```
 a ____ 3
 b ____ 1
 a ____ 1
 b ____ 2
 a ____ 3
 a ____ 2
 a ____ 2
 a ____ 1
 b ____ 2
```

how do +1 all a or b rows? Thank you

Comment: `update` and `where`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- To update all rows where type = a

```
UPDATE A
  SET  A.number = A.number + 1
FROM YourTable AS A
WHERE  A.type = 'a';
```

-- To update all rows where type = b

```
UPDATE A
  SET  A.number = A.number + 1
FROM YourTable AS A
WHERE  A.type = 'b';
```

Comment: You need single quote for string `''`, and you could do it on a single instruction with `WHERE  A.type = 'a' OR A.type = 'b';`  or `WHERE A.type IN ('a', 'b');`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks, in too much of a hurry to get out of the office lol. You could do it on a single instruction with WHERE A.type = 'a' OR A.type = 'b'; or WHERE A.type IN ('a', 'b'); but I'm not sure that's what he was looking for.